# I want to display just a single grade from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried this, but it displays all grades for every student, and I just want one, may be the biggest or the smallest. And I have to do this with JOIN.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID,NAME, max (B.GRADE)
FROM STUDENTS A 
inner JOIN GRADES B 
ON A.ID=B.ID 
WHERE B.GRADE IS NOT NULL
ORDER by A.ID;
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand on Gordon's hint - anytime an aggregation is performed (MIN, MAX, SUM, etc..), the `GROUP BY` clause is required and needs to include all other fields that are SELECTed but not aggregated.